# jQuery not loading into custom js file in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loading

I'm writing a bit of code in a custom js file located in /mytheme/js/live-search.js At the top of the js file I have [ import $ from 'jquery'; ]. In my functions.php i have my wp_enqueue_script function with the dependency of array('jquery'), but I still get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for the first line in that js file when I load the page.

I have this same setup on a local WP site I'm working on and it's working just fine there. What am I missing?

in functions.php

```
function asset_files() {
    wp_enqueue_script('search-jsfile', get_theme_file_uri('/js/live-search.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'asset_files');
```

This is the begining of my code

```
class Search {
    constructor() {
        this.openButton = $("#search-icon-btn");
        this.closebutton = $(".search-overlay__close");
        this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay");
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        this.openButton.on("click", this.openOverlay);
        this.closebutton.on("click", this.closeOverlay);
    }

    openOverlay() {
        this.searchOverlay.addClass("search-overlay--active");
    }

    closeOverlay() {
        this.searchOverlay.removeClass("search-overlay--active");
    }
}

var liveSearch = new Search();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is part of WordPress core. You don't need to import it twice.

Just remove `import $ from 'jquery';` in your **live-search.js** file.

---

**Also, the `import` statement is a part of ES6 features.**

To make ES6 modules work in browsers you should add `type="module"` to script tag like so:

```
<script type="module" src="filename.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, I tried that once before and I got an "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" error when it encountered my first constructor statement 
"this.openButtun = $("#search-icon-btn");"

Comment: Hey Patrik, try to put this in your js file: `(function($) { /* Your code inside here; */ })(jQuery);`

Comment: Thank you for quick responses! That worked for my constructor statements but down in the events section it's throwing me an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' " error for the first a couple of these kinds of statements "this.openButton.on("click", this.openOverlay);"..... :( 
Am i going to end up declaring each jquery function I want to use?

Comment: What exactly error says? Cannot read property 'on' ...? Is this.openButton a jQuery object?

Comment: Sorry the error in full is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

I updated my original questions with the start of my code.

Comment: @PatrikCK thanks, you made typo in word openButtun in your constructor. It should be openButton

Comment: Well that was obvious, thank you. Unfortunately got another error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.openOverlay"
Thanks again so staying tuned!

Comment: @PatrikCK No problem. But this is the topic for another question. Please, close this and create a new one. I can take a look. Because the initial problem (with jQuery) in WordPress was solved.